# Create class or interface with default values to access from everywhere in typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic4

i need to make a class in typescript with default values because i need to access this values from all my app but i dont want to copy and paste the value in every component i need to use it.

this is my class code:

```html
export class WeightScale {
    idIos: string
    idAndroid: string
    name: string 

    constructor(idIos: string = '123456ABC',
                idAndroid: string = 'ABC:321:3567',
                name: string = 'Device1')
    {

        this.idIos = idIos;
        this.idAndroid = idAndroid;
        this.name = name;
    }
     

}
```

but when i try to access to the class id value i get this error:

HomePage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'idAndroid' of undefined

Comment: Show the code that causes the error.

Comment: import { WeightScale } from '../interfaces/weightScale'; then the instance :  devices: WeightScale; and console.log in ngOnInit: ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.devices.idIos)
 }

Comment: Add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a service and then inject it in via the constructor using dependency injection.

In the console you make a new service with:

```
ionic generate service services/WeightScaleService
```

Then set the code to something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeightScaleService {

    constructor() { }

    readonly idIos: string = '123456ABC';
    readonly idAndroid: string = 'ABC:321:3567';
    readonly name: string = 'Device1';
}
```

Then use it in a page like this:

```
  constructor(
    public weightScaleService : WeightScaleService,
  ) {
  }

  something() {
    let ios = this.weightScaleService.idIos;
  }
```

More theory can be read up on here:

- [When to Use Providers / Services / Injectables in Ionic | joshmorony - Learn Ionic & Build Mobile Apps with Web Tech](https://www.joshmorony.com/when-to-use-providersservicesinjectables-in-ionic/)

### However

However I think the actual issue with your code is that you are only assigning the type, not instantiating it:

```
devices: WeightScale = new WeightScale();
```